# Oracle stored procedure challenges

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql, compiler-errors, ora-06550

I'm doing my transition from `T-SQL` TO `PL/SQL`, in my first attempt I'm trying to create a stored procedure (`PL/SQL`) to load data into a table, but I'm getting an error:

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
ORA-06550: line 29, column 4:  
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the  following:
```

Code:

```
declare
  v_str VARCHAR2(32767) := '<ns0:ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ConnItemSvc" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/02/documents/DocumentPaging" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/02/documents/EntityKeyPage" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/QueryCriteria" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKeyList" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ConnCustomerOrg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns2:ConnCustomerOrg>
        <ns2:CustTable class="entity">
            <ns2:AccountNum xsi:nil="true" />
            <ns2:CreditMax>0</ns2:CreditMax>
            <ns2:CustGroup>10</ns2:CustGroup>
            <ns2:Organization class="entity">
                <ns2:NumberOfEmployees xsi:nil="true" />
                <ns2:OrganizationName class="entity">
                    <ns2:Name>PRUEBA</ns2:Name>
                </ns2:OrganizationName>
            </ns2:Organization>
        </ns2:CustTable>
    </ns2:ConnCustomerOrg>
</ns0:ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest>
';
  v_xml XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(v_str);
begin

  select x.AccountNum, x.CreditMax
    from t
      ,XMLTABLE('/ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest/ConnCustomerOrg/CustTable'
              PASSING t.xml
              COLUMNS AccountNum  NUMBER PATH '/CustTable/AccountNum'
                     ,CreditMax   NUMBER PATH '/REC/CreditMax'                     
             ) x

end;
```

Comment: A pure select inside pl/sql must SELECT <list of fields> INTO <corresponding list of variables> WHERE...; You are selecting but not putting the values anywhere. And if your statement can return more than one row then you either have to do it in a loop construct, or bulk collect into a collection.

Comment: You don't have an insert. At the moment you don't seem to actually need PL/SQL, but since you are using it, you have to select *into* something - you need PL/SQL variables to match the result set columns from the query, i.e. two number variables. (Plus the missing semicolon, of course). And what is the `t` table you're selecting from? Have you copied this from a CTE example?

Comment: @AlexPoole  & Michael Broughton!!!!    BEGIN  
WITH t as (select XMLTYPE(v_str) as xml from dual)
select x.AccountNum, x.CreditMax 
from t
    ,XMLTABLE('/ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest/ConnCustomerOrg/CustTable'
              PASSING t.xml
              COLUMNS AccountNum  NUMBER PATH '/CustTable/AccountNum'
                     ,CreditMax   NUMBER PATH '/CustTable/CreditMax'

             ) x;
end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have an INTO clause when you are using a SELECT statement in a PL/SQL. INTO clause lets you store the values in a declared variable/s so you can access them inside the block whenever you want. Try this:

```
declare
  v_str VARCHAR2(32767) := '<ns0:ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ConnItemSvc" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/02/documents/DocumentPaging" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/02/documents/EntityKeyPage" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/QueryCriteria" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKeyList" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ConnCustomerOrg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns2:ConnCustomerOrg>
        <ns2:CustTable class="entity">
            <ns2:AccountNum xsi:nil="true" />
            <ns2:CreditMax>0</ns2:CreditMax>
            <ns2:CustGroup>10</ns2:CustGroup>
            <ns2:Organization class="entity">
                <ns2:NumberOfEmployees xsi:nil="true" />
                <ns2:OrganizationName class="entity">
                    <ns2:Name>PRUEBA</ns2:Name>
                </ns2:OrganizationName>
            </ns2:Organization>
        </ns2:CustTable>
    </ns2:ConnCustomerOrg>
</ns0:ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest>
';


  v_xml XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(v_str);
  v_accountnum VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_creditmax  VARCHAR2(2000);--i just assumed their datatypes since i cannot use %TYPE in here because i dont know what table accountnum and creditmax came from

BEGIN

SELECT x.AccountNum, x.CreditMax
INTO v_accountnum, v_creditmax
FROM t
    ,XMLTABLE('/ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest/ConnCustomerOrg/CustTable'
              PASSING t.xml
              COLUMNS AccountNum  NUMBER PATH '/CustTable/AccountNum'
                     ,CreditMax   NUMBER PATH '/REC/CreditMax'

             ) x;

END;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon `;` after your select statement. Every statement must be terminated with a `;`.

```
declare
  v_str VARCHAR2(32767) := '<ns0:ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ConnItemSvc" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/02/documents/DocumentPaging" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/02/documents/EntityKeyPage" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKey" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/QueryCriteria" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/EntityKeyList" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ConnCustomerOrg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns2:ConnCustomerOrg>
        <ns2:CustTable class="entity">
            <ns2:AccountNum xsi:nil="true" />
            <ns2:CreditMax>0</ns2:CreditMax>
            <ns2:CustGroup>10</ns2:CustGroup>
            <ns2:Organization class="entity">
                <ns2:NumberOfEmployees xsi:nil="true" />
                <ns2:OrganizationName class="entity">
                    <ns2:Name>PRUEBA</ns2:Name>
                </ns2:OrganizationName>
            </ns2:Organization>
        </ns2:CustTable>
    </ns2:ConnCustomerOrg>
</ns0:ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest>
';
  v_xml XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(v_str);
begin
select x.AccountNum, x.CreditMax
from t
    ,XMLTABLE('/ConnCustomerOrgServiceCreateRequest/ConnCustomerOrg/CustTable'
              PASSING t.xml
              COLUMNS AccountNum  NUMBER PATH '/CustTable/AccountNum'
                     ,CreditMax   NUMBER PATH '/REC/CreditMax'

             ) x;

end;
```